# elFinder - Unable to extract files

Tags: jquery, elfinder

I'm using the elFinder file manager and have ran in to a small problem.
Everything is working fine, except for the extract archive feature.
I m able to create archives, but when I click on an archive file (tried 7z, zip, bzip and tar), the extract button is disabled. There is no extract option in the context menu either. I have not disabled any option and all the other options seems to be working without a problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that extract command is disabled. This problem seems like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23227002/2928471